# Use of Ctrl key when teamviewing from Windows to Mac

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, teamviewer

I am using TeamViewer to connect from a Windows laptop to a Mac Mini.

For a long time, I have used the aplication's main menu or the context menu to copy and paste text, and only recently found out that I could actually use keyboard shortcuts instead.

On the Mac, many shortcuts use the `⌘` key, where Windows uses `Ctrl`. For instance, `⌘`+`C` and `Ctrl`+`C` are equivalent. But to enter the shortcut in TeamViewer, I have to use the Windows key, and not `Ctrl`.

Is there a way to configure TeamViewer in a way so that I can use the `Ctrl` key for these keyboard shortcuts?

And related: Some keyboard shortcuts use other keys on the Mac: the *Options* key `⌥`, `fn` and `^`. How can I type these?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for your issue exists in newer MacOS versions.

[image]

In system settings ⚙ you can switch the <kbd>ctrl^</kbd> and <kbd>command⌘</kbd> keys around.

[image]

And after your session, switch them back.

Comment: Looks good. What exactly is 'newer'?

Comment: I dunno, I only know that this works on my MacOS 13.5 Ventura.

Comment: I'll check next week when I'm in the office

Answer (score 0):

TeamViewer [as does any remote connection app] has to translate these commands for you. It's traditional use use the <kbd>⊞ Win</kbd> key as a substitute for  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>  on Mac. Even when you directly connect a Windows keyboard to a Mac, the Mac will read it as  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> .
The Mac is not interested in  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>    <kbd>C</kbd>  for Copy, it will only recognise  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>

Without software translation you cannot send more specialist key commands to the Mac. The  <kbd>Fn</kbd>  key is a special case. It is combined in the keyboard before being sent to the OS, so cannot be translated in most cases.
 <kbd>Opt ⌥</kbd>   &  <kbd>Alt</kbd>   are the same key, they just use a different name. Because Windows often has special uses for right alt, which may conflict, only use left alt to transmit to the Mac.
The ^ sign is language-specific. On English Macs it's shift 6.

Comment: Yes, I understand that a key combination needs to be translated, but my question is: Can TeamViewer do that? I see no technical reason why that wouldn't be possible. But anyway, now that I found the official [documentation](https://community.teamviewer.com/English/kb/articles/109253-use-key-commands-in-sessions-win-macos), I guess the answer unfortunately is 'no'

Comment: Any app like this *could* do it if the devs ever thought about it - but they don't. It's a Windows-biased world out there ;) Parallels will do it for Win running in VM on Mac, you can use either Cmd or Ctrl for such as copy/paste, & I vaguely recall Microsoft's RDC would do it from Mac, but it's been quite a time since I used it… but that's because they see it entirely from the Mac's point of view.

Comment: TeamViewer can do it, but they refuse to. I put in a feature request almost two years ago. I check on it every six months and basically they forget about it and tell me to pound sand. TeamViewer is a really overpriced piece of software for what it does, but the actual screen sharing is more reliable than most.